# cMake SOURCE_GROUP multiple files?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

for a VisualStudio project, i'd like cMake to put all files from a specific folder into a specific filter.

I tried:

```
SOURCE_GROUP(Math FILES 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Math/*.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Math/*.h
)
```

however, this will place only the first found cpp and the first found h file into that filter. the rest of the files in the folder will be placed in the default Filters

How to do it properly?

Comment: Prepare to have trouble with multiple projects: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=3474 This 6 year old bug is still around although someone provided the source code to fix it 3 years ago. AWESOME!

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass full names, not globbing expressions:

```
FILE(GLOB source_files
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Math/*.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Math/*.h
)

SOURCE_GROUP(Math FILES ${source_files})
```